# Playing sound in iOS7 don't seem to work

Tags: ios, audio, ios-simulator, avfoundation

Im having a little problem playing an audio file in iOS7. The audio file doesn't get played because there is no sound when this code is called:

```
NSURL* musicFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PistolShootSound" ofType:@"mp3"]];
AVAudioPlayer *click = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile error:nil];
[click setVolume:1.0];
[click play];
```

But no sound is coming out :(

I have checked the sound on my computer and it is working, I have rechecked the "Play user interface sound effects" option in system preferences but with no use. I have tried opening an AVAudioSession like this:

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];
```

But that didn't work either.

Is there another way to play a sound in iOS7? or doesn't the simulator play sounds anymore?

Comment: Code looks fine for me. Are you sure the object containing the AVAudioPlayer doesn't get deallocated? Does the player think its playing `[click playing]`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this..

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) AVAudioPlayer *click;

@synthesize click;

NSURL* musicFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PistolShootSound" ofType:@"mp3"]];
click = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile error:nil];
[click setVolume:1.0];
[click preparetoPlay];
[click play];
```

Comment: Not adding `prepareToPlay` should normally not affect the ability to play sounds. It just minimizes the lag between calling `play` and the actual sound output.

Comment: By putting the ´click´ in the header file and making it global it now works, I didn't think it would matter but it seems it does.

Comment: @Arbitur, thanks for accepting as answer. But where is my up-vote?? Happy coding!!

Comment: putting the AVAudioPlayer instance in the correct place helped me! Thanks.

Comment: Remember to import the "AVFoundation.framework" first.

Comment: I had the same problem, before putting the player a strong property you it would be released too quickly to let the sound play